# Issue with decorator for unit test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I'm trying to enhance unit tests in python with a decorator.
My decorator looks like this:

```
def report_test(test):
    result = unittest.TestResult()
    result.startTest(test)
    result.stopTest(test)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        # Do something...
```

The main idea here is to run the test case, identify if it succeeded, and act accordingly.

I'd like to use it over a unittest case like this:

```
@report_test
def test_something(self):
    reply = do_request()
    self.assertEqual(Ack.SUCCESS, reply.Ack)
```

The problem is: when I'm executing this particular test case via PyCharm, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: don't know how to make test from: None
```

Any workaround for checking in the decorator the test case result rather than using unittest.TestResult() ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it going inside decorator ? I don't think your decorator is valid.

Comment: Your decorator has to return `test`, so that the test runner has a function to run. Right now, `test_something` is bound to `None`.

Comment: That said, this sounds like a case for writing a custom test runner, not decorating every individual test function.

Comment: @chepner that was quick, thanks! works now.